# Trying to iterate over

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to iterate through a JSON object and wrap each item in the array in an `li` tag.

Here is my JSON structure

```
 var classYear = {
    "1921": [
        'name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4'
    ],
    "1933": [
        'name5', 'name6', 'name7', 'name8'
    ],
   "1943": [
        'name9', 'name10', 'name11', 'name12', 'name13'
    ]
};
```

Here is my javascript

```
var container = document.getElementById('classYearContainer');

function classYearOutput(yClass, yId, listId, key, name) {
    return '<div class="'+ yClass +'" id="'+ yId +'">' + 
        '<h4>' + key + '</h4>' +
        '<ul id="'+ listId +'">' + name + '</ul>' +
        '</div>';
}

function nameList(name) {
  return '<li>' + name + '</li>';
}

for(var year in classYear) {
     container.innerHTML += classYearOutput(
        'category',
          'y-' + year,
         year + '-list',
         year,
            nameList(classYear[year])
  );
}
```

With this setup my output is returning all the names in one `li` as opposed to separate `li` tags.  Strangely, when I `console.log` I get the expected result, but when I `return` it puts all names in the same `li`.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Consider using `createElement` and `appendChild`. Strings are prone to errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is your passing the array into name list, you'll need to loop through the array and create an li for each name.

```
function nameList(names) {
    var out = "";
    names.forEach(function (el) {out += "<li>" + el + "</li>";});
    return out;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/noy3dshx/

Comment: This is it.  Thanks so much for laying it out.

Comment: If you think the answer is correct your should accept it as the correct answer, see here for details: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.

Answer (score 1):

`classYear[year]` is an array, and you're passing it to the nameList function.

You have to iterate in that function as well

```
function nameList(name) {

    var html = '';

    for (var i=0; i<name.length; i++) {
        html += '<li>' + name[i] + '</li>';
    }

    return html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function nameList(names) {
    return names.map(function(name) {
        return '<li>' + name + '</li>';
    });
}
```

Names is an array, so you need to iterate over that instead you are essentially calling the `toString` method of the array which is doing it's best and giving you a comma seperated list of the contents (e.g. `console.log(['a', 'b', 'c'].toString());` or `console.log('' + ['a', 'b', 'c']);`)